# How To Make an Animated Multi-Color Progress Bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, progress-bar

I'm rather new so apologies if what I'm asking isn't exactly clear. I'm trying to build a multi-color progress bar that animates when the page loads. I have found examples similar to what I'm looking for, but the javascript/jquery is what's giving me problems. I'm not skilled in that area.

Example 1: https://codepen.io/tamak/pen/hzEer

That link shows how I want the bar to progressively extend when the page comes up and stop at certain percentages.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.skillbar').each(function(){
    jQuery(this).find('.skillbar-bar').animate({
      width:jQuery(this).attr('data-percent')
    },6000);
  });
});
```

Example 2: http://www.cssflow.com/snippets/animated-progress-bar/demo

Is very very close to what I'm after, but I want the progress bar to function without the buttons. the colors themselves, progressing from red to green, is what I'm trying to achieve.

Thanks in advance! I know it's probably asking for a lot, but I'm hoping someone is willing to give it a try.

Comment: Your second example contains everything you need. But instead of using an onclick event on the button to trigger the change event, just trigger it manually in your code using either a setInterval, if you want the bar to update at specific delays, or tie it to resolution other things, like ajax calls that update the page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help: [Bootstrap progress bar with gradient color showing proportionally on active width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29519868/bootstrap-progress-bar-with-gradient-color-showing-proportionally-on-active-widt)

As for moving the progress bar, how exactly do you want it to change?  You don't need buttons to do it, but something needs to happen.  Could you explain that piece in a little more detail?

Comment: Thanks! That is rather helpful. As for explaining it further. The progress bar for the most part is static. I only need it to change in the beginning. Scaling up from 0% to whatever arbitrary number I need it to (1% - 100%). Pandhi's post is the greatest example of what I'm after thus far

Answer (score 0):

You can setup click events of buttons with time interval, based on percentage.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var CurrentProgress =  '75%';
 setTimeout(function(){
   $(".label").each(function() {
     if($(this).html()==CurrentProgress){
       $(this).click();
      }
    })
  },1000)
})
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 80px auto;
  width: 640px;
  text-align: center;
}
.container .progress {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
}

.progress {
  padding: 4px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08);
}

.progress-bar {
  position: relative;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s linear;
  -moz-transition: 0.4s linear;
  -o-transition: 0.4s linear;
  transition: 0.4s linear;
  -webkit-transition-property: width, background-color;
  -moz-transition-property: width, background-color;
  -o-transition-property: width, background-color;
  transition-property: width, background-color;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
.progress-bar:before, .progress-bar:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.progress-bar:before {
  bottom: 0;
  background: url("../img/stripes.png") 0 0 repeat;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
.progress-bar:after {
  z-index: 2;
  bottom: 45%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05));
}

#five:checked ~ .progress > .progress-bar {
  width: 5%;
  background-color: #f63a0f;
}

#twentyfive:checked ~ .progress > .progress-bar {
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #f27011;
}

#fifty:checked ~ .progress > .progress-bar {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #f2b01e;
}

#seventyfive:checked ~ .progress > .progress-bar {
  width: 75%;
  background-color: #f2d31b;
}

#onehundred:checked ~ .progress > .progress-bar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #86e01e;
}

.radio {
  display: none;
}

.label {
  display: none;
  margin: 0 5px 20px;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  color: #aaa;
  text-shadow: 0 1px black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.radio:checked + .label {
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="container">
    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="progress" value="five" id="five" checked>
    <label for="five" class="label">5%</label>

    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="progress" value="twentyfive" id="twentyfive">
    <label for="twentyfive" class="label">25%</label>

    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="progress" value="fifty" id="fifty">
    <label for="fifty" class="label">50%</label>

    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="progress" value="seventyfive" id="seventyfive">
    <label for="seventyfive" class="label">75%</label>

    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="progress" value="onehundred" id="onehundred">
    <label for="onehundred" class="label">100%</label>

    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar"></div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: It's wonderful! Thanks a ton! You've saved me a lot of headache and time.  I'm not really sure what you mean by click events with time intervals though. However, I am also now wondering if there is a way to setup two bars with different percentages.

Comment: About click events, you would have knowledge about jQuery.