# How I can do this progress bar?

Tags: html, css, progress

[Example of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYUvI.jpg)

Hi, my question is simple, just look at the pic above :)

How I can do that ?

If I put a background on the progress part of the bar, when the progress is on 10%, the background fill all the 10%, but I want to show only 10% of the background !

Maybe the solution is to put a grey progress bar above the 100% gradient progress bar, but I need to make a "reverse" border-radius ... I think that is not possible, so how I can do that ?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29519868/bootstrap-progress-bar-with-gradient-color-showing-proportionally-on-active-widt/29625609

Comment: @RogerNg I disagree with it being a duplicate... there's no mention of "bootstrap progress bar".

Comment: You could add your code here and ask help on that rather than just trying to get a copy paste code from the SO community. I see in the comment section under the answer by @NickGrealy you keep saying it's not working. He gave an answer based on your question he took his time to write that code part for you. If it's not working then work on that code to get it working. And you not event said thank you for his time this is why SO community need to stop answering these type of questions.

Comment: First, it's my first time on SO so I'm sorry if it's not the right way to ask a question. Next, I don't speak english well so I make a picture because it's more easy for my to explain what I need. And you said "And you not event said thank you" but my first comment on NickGrealy's post is "Thanks". Then I ask him some updates because it's not exaclty what I want but it comes close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a background linear gradient for the coloured bar, and set the width to the same as the width of the progress bar.

**i.e.** `background: linear-gradient(to right, yellow, #BD3D3D 100%);`

**e.g.**

```css
.progressbar {
  background: lightgray;
  width: 300px;
  height:20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.progressbar>.progress{
  height:20px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, yellow, #BD3D3D 300px);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

/* set some custom progresses */

.progressbar:nth-child(1)>.progress{
  width: 25%;
}
.progressbar:nth-child(2)>.progress{
  width: 50%;
}
.progressbar:nth-child(3)>.progress{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="progressbar"><div class="progress"></div></div>
<div class="progressbar"><div class="progress"></div></div>
<div class="progressbar"><div class="progress"></div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! It is possible to do the same with % instead of fixed width in px ?

Comment: @Vald - I changed the example to use percentages, as requested.

Comment: But I want that the entire bar is responsive (.progressbar{width:100%;}) if I set the progress bar and the gradient to 100%, it doesn't work :(

Comment: Sure it works... you mean this? -> `#BD3D3D 100%` (example updated)

Comment: I mean .progressbar{width:100%} instead of fixed 300px width, to make the progress bar responsive

Comment: But now it does not work^^ The gradient fill all of the 25% of the bar. Run the snippet and see

Comment: Yeh, my bad. Reverted code. Not sure how to solve with percentages at this point in time.

Answer (score 0):

**Html part**

```
 <div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar">10%</div>
</div>
<button onclick='move()'>Click me</button>
```

**Css part**

```
#myBar {
    width: 10%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    text-align: center; /* To center it horizontally (if you want) */
    line-height: 30px; /* To center it vertically */
    color: white; 
}
```

**Javascript part**

```
function move() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar"); 
    var width = 10;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
    function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            width++; 
            elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
            elem.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but it's not what I need. Look at the screen : I want that the progress bar show the same percentage as the background gradient. For example, if the progress bar is 10%, I want to show only 10% of the gradient (only the yellow, and not the red). Actually I use standard progress bar <progress></progress>